# Наследование __proto__ в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты, prototype

Столкнулся с тем, что JS не ищет свойства прописанные в прототипе во вложенности. Есть ли способ заставить искать вложенные свойства?

```js
var obj = {
  a: {}
};

obj.__proto__ = {
  a: {
    __proto__: {
      b: true
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj.a.b); // undefined

// Нежелательный метод
obj.a.__proto__ = {b:true};
```

Comment: Пытаюсь придумать как сделать расширяемый объект максимально лаконично (объект настроек расширения), поскольку неизвестно как он будет выглядеть в будущем. Приму к сведению иную подсказку реализации такой системы

Comment: абсолютно непонятна цель. которую нужно добиться. попробуй добавить больше описания и примеров в вопрос.

Comment: код не работает просто потому. что в примере свойство `a`  берется не из прототипа, а из основного объекта.

Comment: В этом то и проблема, он видит, что `a` уже существует и забывает про прототип. Затем он ищет в нем свойство `b`, но там его нет и на этом он останавливается.

Comment: Мне нужна система, где при не найденном свойстве, оно бы бралось из другого объекта. Я так понял, что система прототипирования в JS это то, что мне надо

Comment: Боюсь, такого способа нет, только нежелательный метод (к слову, `__proto__` лучше вообще не использовать).

Comment: О прототипах стоит вспоминать только тогда, когда нужно именно наследование. Если Вам нужен похожий механизм, то и создавайте похожий механизм.

Comment: _Мне нужна система, где при не найденном свойстве, оно бы бралось из другого объекта_ - смотри в сторону [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: @Grundy, Вы чего? Прокси для взаимодействия с существующими свойствами...Для расширения возможностей объекта без его изменения. Но это не механизм для построения древовидной структуры. Как Вы можете советовать лечение по симптомам описанными самим больным?

Comment: Автор, что Вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: У меня есть расширение в магазине Chrome, там используется файл настроек. Расширение развивается, добавляются новые функции и настройки, но у пользователей уже созданы старые файлы настроек. Соответственно каждое обновление я пишу костыль, который добавляет новые пункты в старый файл настроек. Мне надоело, я хочу использовать как прототип отдельный, всегда актуальный объект. Если у пользователя нет определенного пункта в сохраненном файле настроек -- пускай он берется из всегда актуального. Но вводя такую систему я столкнулся с проблемами вложенности, когда __proto__ перестает работать

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у на клиенте хранятся настройки в файле, который Вы грузите в приложение, которому могут потребоваться значения отсутствующие в конфигурации пользователя. В таком случаи самый простой вариант динамически расширять конфигурацию пользователя -

```js
let prevSettings = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1
};

let currentSettings = {
  b: 2,
  c: 2
};

console.log(Object.assign({}, prevSettings, currentSettings)); // a: 1, b: 2, c: 2
console.log(Object.assign({}, currentSettings, prevSettings)); // a: 1, b: 1, c: 2
```

Как видно первый вариант создает новый объект но изменяет значения предыдущего объекта, в отличии от второго варианта, который лишь добавляет новые-несуществующие свойства, оставляя существующие нетронутыми.

Если это не подходит, то объясните более подробно.

Comment: Этот вариант подходит, так наверное и придется сделать.

Comment: Просто мне казалось с прототипами всё полегче

Comment: О прототипах стоит думать лишь на этапе разработки, когда Вы пишите код.А запущенная программа ничего не должна знать о прототипах и внутреннем устройстве. На самом деле это нормальный механизм, когда сливаются конфиги.